# Size and color of <md-icon> in Angular Material

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am successfully displaying an icon in my app, the `account_circle` icon, using Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.3, like this:

```
<md-icon>account_circle</md-icon>
```

I have included `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in my app.

However, none of the recommended ways of increasing the size of the icon using the `md` classes seem to work. How do I change the size without resorting to a font size? And how can I change the color to be the same color as the input box placeholders?

**Update**

Ok, I've got the icon changing size by applying the font size directly to the icon itself, like this:

```
<div fxFlexAlign="center"><md-icon style="font-size:48px;">account_circle</md-icon></div>
```

However, now I have the problem that the icon is not completely centered — it looks like it's using a single quadrant of the image to calculate the centering so is not quite right. What is the best way to center an enlarged Material icon like this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the size of the md-icon, not only the font-size :

```
<md-icon style="font-size:48px; width: 48px; height:48px;">
```

or create a new class:

```
<md-icon class="md-48">

.md-48 {
  font-size:48px; 
  width: 48px;
  height:48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To change the md-icon size, add this to your CSS:**

```
md-icon {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  height:48px;
}
```

**To change the md-icon color, add this to your CSS:**

```
md-icon {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
```